# Why datagridview needs double click to sort column

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a problem with automatic sort of datagridview.
When I click column header once, it's values are sorted but the triangle mark stays unchanged, so it points wrong direction.
On second click, it's the triangle that changes (it will now point different direction, but correct when you compare it with values in datagridview)
And then, the sorting process repeats - so if I want to sort column, I have to click header twice: first to change direction mark/glyph, and second to sort values.

I don't really think it is important here, but for this DGV I used BindingList as data source.

Designer code:

```
        // 
        // dgv
        // 
        this.dgv.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgv.Columns.AddRange( new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.monthColumn,
        this.colorColumn} );
        this.dgv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point( 22, 127 );
        this.dgv.Name = "dgv";
        this.dgv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 468, 164 );
        this.dgv.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dgv.CellBeginEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventHandler( this.dgv_CellBeginEdit );
        this.dgv.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler( this.dgv_CellClick );
        this.dgv.CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler( this.dgv_CellEndEdit );
        this.dgv.RowsAdded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler( this.dgv_RowsAdded );
        // 
        // monthColumn
        // 
        this.monthColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.monthColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
        this.monthColumn.HeaderText = "Miesiące";
        this.monthColumn.Name = "monthColumn";
        this.colorColumn.ValueType = typeof( int );
        this.monthColumn.Width = 72;
        // 
        // colorColumn
        // 
        this.colorColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewCellStyle4.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.colorColumn.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
        this.colorColumn.HeaderText = "Barwa";
        this.colorColumn.Name = "colorColumn";
        this.colorColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        this.colorColumn.ValueType = typeof( System.Drawing.Color );
```

Binding procedure:

```
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        monthColumn.DataPropertyName = "Months";
        colorColumn.DataPropertyName = "Color";
        colorColumn.ReadOnly = false;
        dgv.DataSource = bcolors;//BindingList
        dgv.Sort( monthColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

event methods are used to apply backgroundcolor to rows and disallow editing colorColumn (readonly doesn't work ?, but that's not the point here)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by changing the sortmode of the column?

change this:

```
this.colorColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

into this:

```
this.colorColumn.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything in my case, also I really don't want this column to be sortable, that's why I used NotSortable setting.